# Where does Reporting Services store its log files

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

The most relevant google result seems to indicate that in order to access the logs we have to depoly our own log tables to the database and make [Reporting Services write to it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157403.aspx).

Simply put: surely there must be plain text log files for Reporting Services? If yes, where are these files stored?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming you installed SQL 2008 to the default location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: or here - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SS2008. SS2008 is the name of of your instance, ie the one you gave it during installation. If you used default name at that time, then it is MSSQLSERVER.