# Another rsAccessDenied problem with SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I've read through a lot of posts regarding the problem, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me. I continue to get an error stating, *"The permissions granted to user '\Rich' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)."* If I am logged in as the local administrator account, entering the Reporting Services URL in IE doesn't give me that error, but it takes me to a blank page. I haven't been able to get to a SSRS home page at all.

Order of operations:
I installed and patched Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
I installed SQL Server Express 2008 with Advanced Services using the MS web installer.
I downloaded and installed SP1 for SQL Server Express 2008.

I've tried running IE as administrator, adding local machine to trusted sites, and just about every other suggestion I've found. I even ran the entire installation logged in as the local administrator. Nothing seems to work. Could someone please tell me, considering the above installation process, what I *should* expect to do after to make this work?

Comment: Do the reporting services log files have any information that might help you?  (see here if you don't know where log files are stored: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491389/where-does-reporting-services-store-its-log-files)

Comment: Bob, I would up vote this as an answer if it helps him solve his problem.  It's helped me before.  Rich - check the log file here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running SQL Reporting Services 2005 on Windows 7. I could not get rid of the rsAccessDenied error upon trying to deploy the reports or access the url "http://localhost/reportserver".I tried so many suggestions from many forums but nothing worked for me. Finally the following solution worked for me.

My solution:

1.Open IIS manager, select the "ReportSever" website from the list of websites on the left.

2.Click "Basic Settings" from the actions on the right side.

3.Click "Connect As", provide your windows login credentials and click "Set".

Mahesh N

To test if this solved your issue, you can click the "Test Settings" button. If you see a green tick before "Authentication" and "Authorization", then you can Eureka.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access reporting server from your web application you must add `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` in new role assignment in report manager and give it every permission that you want.

if you want to add permission to a person that exist in a domain, you must add this user like below :

```
MY_DOMAIN\MY_USER_NAME
```

and give the needed permissions to this user.

Comment: Just a couple of points: this is all running on my laptop, and I never get to the report manager. I get the above error when trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Extra work needed on Windows higher than XP...

Read these which pretty much cover all bases...

[How to: Configure a Report Server for Local Administration on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430.aspx)

[Installing Reporting Services on Windows 7, Vista or Windows Server 2008](http://blogical.se/blogs/jahlen/archive/2009/10/02/setting-up-sql-server-reporting-services-on-windows-7-vista-or-windows-2008.aspx)

[Report Manager in Windows 7](http://blogs.digineer.com/blogs/jasons/archive/2009/09/07/report-manager-in-windows-7.aspx)

Comment: In the 2008R2 page of first link, I do not understand what step 13 means. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430(v=sql.105).aspx   In Report Manager, on the Home page, click Folder Settings.

Answer (score 0):

When launching Internet Explorer, right click and launch it as administrator.

Comment: In his third paragraph, "I've tried running IE as administrator, ..."  @Rich.Carpenter - Are you logging in as an administrator and using IE, or using Run As?

Comment: Both. Logging in as a local administrator as well as using "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

I am using 64-bit Windows 7 and 64-bit SQL Server 2005. The "permission insufficient" error is not new to me. It happened to me on multiple machines, and it was always resolved in one way or another. On this particular 64-bit machine, I tried many solutions to no avail, until I tried Mahesh's suggestion above.

Just for clarification, my SQL installation was configured by the installation program automatically. Reporting service web service is running as "Network Service", and its Windows service is running as "Local System", and the ReportServer application pool is running as "Network Service". The only thing I did was, as Mahesh suggested, configure the ReportServer virtual directory (application) to "Connect As..." an administrator account, and that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Have you given yourself administrative rights to SQL Server 2008?  I don't think it automatically gives Administrator rights during installation, other than for the SQL sa account if using Mixed Mode Authentication.  I ask because it's not mentioned in your list of steps in the question.

See step #16 here:
[How to Install SQL Server 2008 (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)

"SQL Server Administrators — You must specify at least one system administrator for the instance of SQL Server. To add the account under which SQL Server Setup is running, click Add Current User. To add or remove accounts from the list of system administrators, click Add or Remove, and then edit the list of users, groups, or computers that will have administrator privileges for the instance of SQL Server. "

Comment: I did specify "Add Current User" during the SQL Server installation, yes.